# Voltage drop in TIP122

Tags: power-supply, transistors, power-electronics, voltage

I was working with the TIP122 in which I used the following circuit. I used the 33 ohm resistor in parallel with the 330ohm res shown. Initially the TIP122 worked fine.On an input of 12V at the base it gave 10.6 with 33 ohm and 10.7 without the 33 ohm. I then swiched off the circuit and after an hour checked, it gave 9.5V as I added the 33 ohm resistor in parallel to the 330ohm. I dont know what had gone wrong. Can there be a problem of the TIP122?? Kindly help me.
[image]

the input comes from a power supply. The variable resistor takes input from a voltage regulator.

Comment: Please add to the body of your question: After said hour, what was the base voltage, the output voltage `without the 33 ohm`? What is the collector voltage, anyway? *Which* `resistor takes input from a voltage regulator`?

Comment: The variable resistor

Comment: Please measure voltages at the Base, Collector, and between the Base and Emitter, with and without the 33 ohm resistor. Can you show us a photo of the setup?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ive done a setup on a breadboard and its a bit messed up

Comment: Breadboards often get bad connections which cause excessive voltage drop at high current. Measure voltages directly on the transistor pins to verify the connections.

Comment: Yes I also think that's the problem. I also made some very short connections and use abit better wires instead of jumpers. That gave me good results.